# Angularjs + Cordova + HTML - how to load files in ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, file-transfer

Anyone been able to load cordova downloaded html files using angular?

```
.state('test', {
                url: "/test",
                views: {
                    'test': {
                        templateUrl: "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/tpl/test.html"
                    }
                }
            });
```

An absolute url won't work, but an external link should work..
Anyways, has anyone done this or have an idea of how I can do this?

Comment: Good question, wondering about that myself.